# ExtGWT Resizing TabPanel (TabItem) with ChartsVizualization an ChartsTable

Tags: gwt, layout, gxt

The problem is on the drawing by click or resizing browser. I have TabPanel placed with RowData, two TabItems with Chart (Google Vizualization) on one and Table with the same Data on the next. I create them on the page loading. 
Then I click on Load Data (button) from DB, I redraw this two:

```
    public void reDraw(final List<Double> slices, final String[] devices)
    {
        pcPie.draw(createTable(slices,devices),createOptions("По автомобилям"));
        tPie.draw(createTable(slices, devices),CreateTableOptions());
    }
```

That's work only for active TabItem and replace the drawing space from behind with this size (400px;200px) in generated HTML and I find that Data isn't changed at the behind section.

Also, when I resized the browser, Charts and Tables aren't resizing. I've tryed to use some of Layout, they don't work. May be I don't understand exactly how can use them correctly.
So,

1. How can I resize my Charts and Tables correct in the both of the
   section (active and behind)?
2. How can I resize my Charts and Tables
   on the browser resizing events?

Answer (score 0):

Our first problem came from this: when you use the TabPanel component with some TabItems, behind TabItems aren't being created exactly, and you can not redraw them, cause object isn't created. So we change our code in activated section:

```
public void run() { 
    tpLineCharts.setBorders(true);                 
        TabItem tiGraph = new TabItem("График");
            tableData = createTable();
            lcLines = new LineChart(tableData, 
                                    createOptions("По компании"));
            lcLines.addSelectHandler(createSelectHandler(lcLines)); 
        tiGraph.setLayout(new FitLayout());
        tiGraph.add(lcLines);
    tpLineCharts.add(tiGraph);  
        TabItem tiTable = new TabItem("Таблица");                      
            tLine = new Table(tableData, CreateTableOptions());                                                 
        tiTable.add(tLine);                                               
        tiTable.addListener(Events.Select, new Listener<BaseEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {                                           
                tLine.draw(tableData);
            }
        });
    tpLineCharts.add(tiTable);                  
}}, CoreChart.PACKAGE, Table.PACKAGE);
```

where tableData - AbstractTableData. After this modification we can redraw our components:

```
public void reDrawLineChart(final ArrayList <Double> sumCompanyTraffic, 
    final ArrayList<Integer> axisName, String title)
{          
    tableData =createTable(sumCompanyTraffic, axisName); 
    tLine.draw(tableData, CreateTableOptions());
    lcLines.draw(tableData, createOptions(title));
}
```

Also you need to add this options:

```
private Options createOptions(String title) 
{
    Options options = Options.create();
    options.setTitleX("Период");                
    options.setTitle(title);     
    if(tpLineCharts.isRendered())
        options.setSize(tpLineCharts.getWidth(true), 
                tpLineCharts.getHeight(true));

    return options;
}
```